# ActiveRecord Rails How do you query for an associated model in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association on my `PartnerItem` model :

```
class PartnersItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :partner
end
```

Item can be a `program` or a `session`

`Program` is also linked to `sessions` in a `has_many` relationship : `Program has_many Sessions`

I need to find all `Programs` to which a `partner_item` is linked. That means

Any `program` / `item` associated to a specific partner

Any `program` linked to a `session/item` associated to a specific partner.

Finally the query results need to be unique, meaning a `Program` can't appear twice in the results

I am having a hard time figuring out how to assemble such query.

This retrieves all `items` for a specific `partner` but Im stuck on what are the next steps

```
  PartnerItem.where(
     partner: current_partner
   ).items
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do could be like this:

```
program_ids = PartnerItem.where(partner: current_partner, item_type: 'Program').pluck(:item_id)
program_ids += Session.joins(:partner_items).where(partner_items: { partner_id: partner.id }).where.not(program_id: nil).pluck(:program_id)
Program.where(id: program_ids.uniq)
```

This would probably return all the `Program` records which have a `PartnerItem` directly or through `Session`.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
partner_items = PartnerItem.where(partner: current_partner)
problem_ids = partner_items.filter { |x| x.item_type == "Program" }.map(&:item_id)
session_ids = partner_items.filter { |x| x.item_type == "Session" }.map(&:item_id)
Problem.joins(:sessions)
.where("problems.id IN (?) OR sessions.id IN (?)", problem_ids, session_ids)
.distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is almost what you:

```
current_partner.partners_items
```

want except then you get models with a reference to the program or to the session and when the session you want the program it belongs to.

In SQL this would be:

```
SELECT programs.*
FROM programs
  INNER JOIN partners
    ON partners.item_type = 'Program' and partners.item_id = programs.id
WHERE partners.id = ?

UNION

SELECT programs.*
FROM programs
  INNER JOIN sessions
    ON sessions.program_id = programs.id
  INNER JOIN partners
    ON sessions.item_type = 'Session' and partners.item_id = sessions.id
WHERE partners.id = ?
```

Because the joins have a different structure the SQL is going to need a UNION or a subquery which is hard to express in one query using ActiveRecord.

First I would add scopes for the polymorphic types.

```
class PartnersItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :partner

  scope :programs, -> { where(type: 'Program') }
  scope :sessions, -> { where(type: 'Session') }
end
```

Then you might query for the program ids and the session ids for the current partner and use that in the final query.

```
partner_program_ids = current_partner.partners_items.programs.pluck(:id)
partner_session_ids = current_partner.partners_items.sessions.pluck(:id)

Program.joins(:session)
    .where("programs.id = :partner_program_ids
           OR sessions.id = :partner_session_ids",
           partner_program_ids: partner_program_ids,
           partner_session_ids: partner_session_ids)
```